# Getting images and description of a webpage using its link in ASP.Net

Tags: c#, asp.net

hi i am making a website in asp.net which is like social netwroking. users shares their updates and views. i am able to complete all modules but now stucked at a requirement.

i want to get images (not screenshot of page) and description from webpage link, when entered by user into the update status bar. just like facebook do. when we enter some link, it gets its thumbnail images and also some desription of that page.

can someone give me direction how can this be done in asp.net. is there some pluggin or code available..

thanks in advance

Comment: I think you should check out [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787497/generating-thumb-nail-image-of-a-web-page-in-a-link) previous post

Answer (score 4):

You need to:

1. Download the webpage

   `var html = new System.Net.WebClient().DownloadString(url);`
2. Parse it as HTML document, or just use Regex to find all image tags. Have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/138892/944681) for details.
3. To read meta description - again already answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1747183/944681).

You could also have a look at [Html Agility Pack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/).

Comment: Thumbs up for Html Agility Pack, it's a better way to get the images since you will be treating the html as what it is, a markup language and not just random text. It also makes it a lot easier to extract other information from the page if something else is wanted later on in the project.

Answer (score -2):

You can generate a preview thumbnail image of a web page using the link for the page and get meta description.

This [previous post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2787497/generating-thumb-nail-image-of-a-web-page-in-a-link) and this code could be helpful:

```
System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser web = new System.Windows.Forms.WebBrowser();
web.ScrollBarsEnabled = false;
web.ScriptErrorsSuppressed = true;
web.Navigate("http://www.your_url.com/with_params");

while (web.ReadyState != WebBrowserReadyState.Complete)
Application.DoEvents();

//this is where we start search the DOM for our meta information and extract the content attribute into a usable string.
String meta = (web.Document.GetElementsByTagName("meta")[0]).GetAttribute("content");
System.Console.WriteLine("Meta Value is {0}", meta);
```

Comment: Isn't it far more easy to do with with System.Net.WebClient() ?. You are suggesting to add the enteri system.windows.forms namespace just to fetch a page and also a browser object where as it is absolutely unnecessary.

Comment: @MurtuzaKabul you are it right was a mistake. I copied this snipped from my old code.